# In Google Chrome for Android, how to remove permanently all the visited pages icons - or restore all the removed ones

Tags: chrome-for-android

I want to have a clear new tab page in Chrome so that I don't get suggestions on what to browse. For that reason I pressed each of the icons on it and remove them. However new ones keep appearing all the time.

[image]

I looked everywhere in Google and played with the chrome://flags but they keep appearing all the time.

For that reason I would like one of the following options:

1. make sure I have a clean new tab page with no icons of websites at all. Or in case this is not possible
2. to revert all the removals so that at least I see the pages I like the most but where removed (I didn't clear my browsing history because I have kept it for years and I'd like to keep it)

Also I've uninstalled the Chrome app but didn't help.

Comment: As an alternative, if needed be, you can use Kiwi browser (Chromium based) which doesn't show the visited site icons at all.

Comment: I'd like to stick to Google Chrome but if I don't find the way then I'll consider alternatives